# Bad quality of preview in Android Studion

Tags: android-studio

After the last Android Studio update, the rendering quality of the preview became poor. The "TEXT" on button seems sharpy like if it was a low-pixel screen. However, it looked OK before the update.  How can this be fixed?

[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEMdR.png)

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: The "TEXT" on button seems sharpy like if it was a low-pixel screen. However, it looked OK before the update.

Comment: Exact version numbers might be useful here- not everyone would be running the same version